Theorem I-40 The Geometry of schemes
In theorem I-40 of The Geometry of Schemes by Eisenbud-Harris , we are willing to prove

For any scheme $X$ and any ring $R$, the morphisms $$\left(\psi,\psi^{\#}\right)\colon X \longrightarrow Spec R$$ are in one to one correspondence with the homomorphisms of rings $$\varphi \colon R \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \left(X\right)$$
by the association
$$\varphi = \psi^{\#}(Spec R) \colon R = \mathcal{O}_{Spec R}(Spec R) \longrightarrow \psi_*(\mathcal{O}_X)(Spec R)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$$

We proceed by describing the inverse association, fixing a ring homomorphism $\phi$, and I have no issues with the continuous map defined between the topological spaces $\psi$ defined by sending any point $p$ of the topological space $|X|$ into the prime ideal of $R$ which corresponds to the maximal ideal of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$.
Then we want to define the sheaf's morphism, and here it says

For each basic open set $U=Spec R_f \subset Y$, define the map $\psi^{\#} \colon R_f =\mathcal{O}_Y(U) \longrightarrow (\psi_*\mathcal{O}_X)(U)$ to be the composite $$R_f \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(X)_{\varphi(f)} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X({\psi^{-1}U})$$
obtained by localizing $\psi$.

This is the point where I'm having many problems.
I know that we are going from $R_f$ to $\mathcal{O}_X(X)_{\varphi(f)}$ by localizing the homomorphism $\varphi$, but I don't know how we are going from this ring to $\mathcal{O}_X(\psi^{-1}U)$, and I don't even understand what the "localizing $\psi$" part means.
I was thinking about sending any elements $\frac{s}{\varphi(f)^n}\in\mathcal{O}_X(X)_{\varphi(f)}$ into $\rho^X_{\psi
^{-1}U}(s)\in\mathcal{O}_X(\psi^{-1}U)$, where $\rho^X_{\psi
^{-1}U}$ denotes the restriction morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$ from $X$ to $\psi^{-1}U$, but I wasn't even able to prove that this is well defined, so I doubt I'm on the right way.
If any of you have any hint on how to interpret the "localizing $\psi$" part, I will be very grateful.

Claim. $\varphi(f)$ becomes invertible when restricted to $\psi^{-1}U$.
If you have this, the map $\mathcal O_X(X)_{\varphi(f)} \to \mathcal O_X(\psi^{-1}U)$ comes from the universal property of localisations.
Proof of the claim. By the definition of $U$ and $\psi$, the open $\psi^{-1} U$ consists of all points $p \in X$ with $$\varphi(f)_p \in \mathcal O_{X,p} \setminus \mathfrak m_p.$$
This means that $\varphi(f)_p$ is invertible in $\mathcal O_{X,p}$. Let $g_p \in \mathcal O_{X,p}$ be the inverse. Then there exists an open neighbourhood $V_p$ of $p$, and a section $g_{V_p} \in \mathcal O_X(V_p)$ which restricts to $g_p$ at $p$. Shrinking $V_p$ we may furthermore assume that
$$\varphi(f) \cdot g_{V_p} = 1$$
on $V_p$ (this equality holds on the stalk $\mathcal O_{X,p}$, so it has to hold on a neighbourhood). Now suppose $q \in \psi^{-1}U$ is another point. Then $g_{V_p}$ and $g_{V_q}$ are both inverses to $\varphi(f)$ on $V_p \cap V_q$, and since inverses are unique, you get
$$g_{V_p}|_{V_p\cap V_q} = g_{V_q}|_{V_p \cap V_q}.$$
This means you can glue the local sections $g_{V_p}$ to a section $g \in \mathcal O_X(\psi^{-1}U)$. $\quad\square$

Note that we have actuallly proved the following:

Let $X$ be a scheme. Given a section $s \in \mathcal O_X(X)$, which is invertible at every point $p \in X$, then $s$ has an inverse in $\mathcal O_X(X)$.


Hi, I do actually have a question, I don't know if I should open another question, if so I'm sorry. It is about the continuity of $\psi$, I hadn't checked it when I asked this cause I thought it was easy but now I can't see it.
I can't see a way to prove it because we don't know the topology we have on $X$. I think we should use the hypothesis of $X$ being scheme and use the open neighbourhood of a point that exists by definition to prove it, but I can't see how to relate a generical open of $Spec R$ with those open sets.

@Francesco Take an affine open $U=\operatorname{Spec} S\subset X$, which is a neighborhood of $p$. Then you have a composed ring map $R\to\mathcal O(X)\to\mathcal O(U)=S$. The morphism $\psi: |U| \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is then the usual thing belonging to the composition of ring maps. (I think if you need any more assistance, better ask a new question).
